# Newbie trying to get a like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am setting up a business page for our families' business and I would like to have a "like" button instead of having the "add friend" button. I want people to be able to just hit "like" and instantly receive my status updates in their newsfeeds instead of having to wait until I confirm them as a friend. How do I do this?

I found something about a code for add a like button but I am not sure where I am supposed to enter the code.

Could someone give me step by step instructions on how to do this please? I would be so grateful! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You need a page not a user.
You can create your own business page in https://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php

Answer (score 0):

You can generate code that can easily be copy and pasted into a webpage from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

If you've already created a 'user' profile which represents a business you can learn more about the migration process to a Page here: https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=18918

The process for migrating the existing email address and password to be for managing the Page and not for being a user profile is the same URL 'pricco' shared, except with an extra parameter: https://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php?migrate=1

(**be very careful not to accidentally migrate your own Facebook account**)